# Google Sheets - Script to count how many times a drop down selection is made

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to scripting in general and have been putting together a spreadsheet for work.  I have included a link to an image of the layout of the sheet, minus anything not related to the problem.

Spreadsheet Layout[image]

Currently, I have the sheet setup to make a timestamp every time a selection is made from the drop down list in column G.  The drop down options are: "In Progress", "Submitted for Approval", and "Approved".

The code I'm using for the timestamp is as follows:

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 7 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     var time = new Date();
     time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "America/New_York", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
     nextCell.setValue(time);
 };
}
```

What I am trying to do now is make counters in columns I and J, so I can see how many times "Submitted for Approval" and "Approved" are selected per row.
So in the end we would have every time we select a new status, we get a new timestamp (which currently works perfectly) - but if "Submitted for Approval" is selected then you get the timestamp plus a +1 in Submitted Number (Column I).  And then the same for "Approved" in Column J.

I have no idea how to proceed from here.  What do I add to my script to get the +1's in the other columns based on selection?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome. Questions on this site should be specific. You already told us what you want to achieve but you didn't said if get stuck somewhere. Usually it's better to include an explicit question than something like "any help is welcome".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier than you've imagined it to be. So I think, if you select "Submitted to Approval" then the number at column I will increase by 1, and if you select "Approval" then the number at column J increase by 1 ? This is just a simple `If` statement. Or `Switch`, if you prefer.

I added some more code at the end of your onEdit function. See if it works for you.

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
   var r = s.getActiveCell()
   if( r.getColumn() == 7 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1)
     var time = new Date()
     time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "America/New_York", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm")
     nextCell.setValue(time)

//-------------------- New code added as below -------------------------------

     var colNum = 0 
     if (r.getValue() == "Submitted to Approval") {
       colNum = 2
     }
     else if (r.getValue() == "Approval") {
       colNum = 3
     }
     if (colNum > 0) {
       var editCell = r.offset(0,colNum) // gets the offset selected by r
       var number = editCell.getValue() // gets the value, increase it by 1 and set it back
       number = number + 1
       editCell.setValue(number)
       } // colnum > 0
     } //r.getColumn() == 7
   } // onEdit
```

Of course colNum is hard coded based on your sheet's column, and it's not recommended. But that's another matter..

There's also the issue that when G was already in "Approved" state, and you select "Approved" once more, onEdit won't trigger since google sheet decided that you did not "change" anything, thus the number of "Approved" column will stay the same. I don't know if your sheet is built to behave like this or not, so I only point it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly!

I haven't been able to really play with the new code yet, so I will let you know how it goes once I do.  Initially just pasting it in - I was just getting the timestamp update and not the counters.  Though reading your code, it does look exactly like what I would want it to do.  Also the not counting when hitting "Approved" multiple times in a row is fine.  We actually have a lot of other states and those would be selected before going back to "Approved".

Comment: If code doesn't work, refresh the sheet and try again. I have run the code in my sheet and it does increase the number inside the column the way it is intended to do. On a side note, onEdit is a little tricky to debug, so you will probably want to write out colNum to a cell to see if the `if` statement is doing its job ? then write the value of editCell to see if it actually the correct cell you think it is ?